# Is there any way to realize IE is closing?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

How can I realize IE is closing in asp.net? I want to do something in sql when the user close the IE by IE close button.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the JavaScript onUnload event and send an AJAX request to your ASP.NET app. Be aware the onUnload event fires when the user leaves the page for any reason, not just by clicking the IE close button.

See http://www.livelearncode.com/archives/11 and http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3879500.htm for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

[Using ASP.NET to Prompt a User to Save When Leaving a Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103544/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101304-1.aspx) can be of some help.